# Android Custom ListView with sections

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]
I want to make a ListView like the one below. The ListItems will be grouped into sections and different sections have different item count. how do i get started??

**N.B. I want the section headers on the side. i may also mention the items are queried from the database and sections are for now calculated based on a column in the table.**

Comment: read the android documentation?

Comment: may be you can go for expandable list view..

Comment: do you really need this? It's quite hard to do such listview. If you do not have lot items you better use linearlayout (vertical) for base view and linearlayout (horizontal) for each section.

Comment: how do i get the section headers on the side? and i thought about expandable list view but i don't need the sections to expand, i need them to stretch to the total height of its items.

Comment: @user1969053 look at my answer and follow it closely to acheive great results Inshallah,Its quite easy,reliable and quick to implement

Comment: how many items in each section do you have?

Comment: it's variable. sections can have different number of items

Comment: @Shuvo If my answer helped/solved your question then please mark it as an answer to help others here on SO.

Comment: i will. but i haven't found the solution. i need the section header on the side and stretched to wrap it's items like the image

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found something exactly what you need.
You need to implement separate adapters for sectionItem and EntryItem in this particular example which i am showing you.

Presuming that you know how to handle adapters and ListItems (customised with your own `item.xml`), [this is a full fledged tutorial for how to make sections and entries.(Solution #2)](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/)

In the tutorial,the code to xml layout is also given but you may make your own custom layout for the section and entryitems.Its pretty easy and straightforward.

So that it will come off like this:

[image: Custom ListView]

Comment: This shows how to add sections and entries like the picture above, but doesn't show what the author is trying to do, which is having sections on the side of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

Use expandable listViews, here is example http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html and for more info refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

here also some examples:

[Link1](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/android-expandable-list-example.html) [Link2](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)